# ngx-modal dialog stuck in overlay and not editable

Tags: ngx-modal

I am using ngx-modal, and when I trigger the modal dialog it appears stuck in the overlay and is unresponsive. I suspect it has something to do with the z-index. How do fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

well z-index property specifies the stack order of an element

so make sure that modal has greater stack order .

( check the z-index of your modal and the one behind the modal . make sure z-index of your modal is higher ).